# Mailbox is a ForkJoinTask but the ExecutorService can be a ThreadPoolExecutor: is this fine?

Tags: concurrency, akka

In Akka 2.6.10, the Mailbox is a `ForkJoinTask` as well as a `Runnable`.

```scala
private[akka] abstract class Mailbox(val messageQueue: MessageQueue)
    extends ForkJoinTask[Unit]
    with SystemMessageQueue
    with Runnable {

  // Runnable method
  override final def run(): Unit = {
    // ...
    processMailbox()
    dispatcher.registerForExecution(this, false, false)
    // ...
  }

  // ForkJoinTask method
  final override def exec(): Boolean = {
    // ...
    run()
    // ...
  }
}
```

But the executor service can be configured to use `TheadPoolExecutor` (TP) rather than `ForkJoinPool` (FJ). Therefore it is possible that a TP executes a `ForkJoinTask`.

This maybe totally reasonable but the fact that a TP executes an FJ task looks a bit weird to me. Can anyone share the decision reasoning here? How does `ForkJoinTask` benefit Akka even if it can be executed by a `TheadPoolExecutor`?